# pass on - pass down / passed on - passed-on

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between pass on and pass down?

E.g. "Local knowledge is passed on orally or within practice from one generation to the next." *or* "Local knowledge is passed down orally or within practice from one generation to the next."

Is it possible to use it as an adjective: e.g. passed on knowledge/passed down knowledge. If this is possible, would you write it with hyphen or without (passed on or passed-on)

Comment: The main distinction I make, though subtle, is that "pass on" implies a transference that could take place between any two people in any direction (friend to friend, boss to employee, random passer-by to old lady in the street etc.), whereas "pass down" implies a closer familial connection between the passer and the passee, with the transference being solely downwards in the hierarchy. (father to son, for example, but not son to father). If I were using it as an adjective, I'd hyphenate it as the "on" is part of "passed" and doesn't solely describe the knowledge. So "passed-on knowledge".

Answer (score 2):

I would say that to "pass on" knowledge implies that the type of knowledge is more like general information with a relatively short-term validity and  simply given to the next person.

"Passing down" knowledge implies knowledge that is is of a much longer-term significance and is  being passed from someone older to someone considerably younger, with something of an emotional link between the two people concerned. Like father and son, or a craftsman and apprentice.

As an adjective, I would use the hyphen.

Comment: Yes; the horizontal (equivalent-distribution) metaphor vs the downwards (master-apprentice or elder-youth) metaphor.